# Plot Sensor data in real time using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, real-time

I have a sensor which gives data nearly 500 times a second which I have interfaced to an Arduino and I am reading the data using Python since I will be processing it as the next step.

I tried using `FuncAnimation` from Matplolib.

This is the animate function:

```
def animate(i):
    global data

    # Data comes as one sample per line
    char = ''
    res = ''
    while char != b'\n':
        char = s.read()
        res += char.decode("utf-8")
    res = res[:-1] # To remove a \r added by arduino

    data = data[1:] + [float(res)]

    ax.set_ylim(min(data), max(data))

    line.set_ydata(data)
    return line,
```

I am calculating the approximate time to get a single value using this code:

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
while count < 1000:
    char = s.read()
    if char == b'\n':
        count += 1
        print(count)

end = datetime.datetime.now()

T = ((end - start).total_seconds()) / 1000
```

and finally initializing the animation as:

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=T * 1000, blit=False)
```

This is working fine when I average around five values on the Arduino and then plot, it works but python crashes when I run it at full speed which makes me believe that the issue is speed-related. Also, even when I do average the values, the plot is lagging behind the real action by around 5 seconds.

How can I plot all the values in real-time?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of operations, such as growing immutable strings by concatenation, or concatenating lists, might not seem to be too time-consuming in most circumstances, but can be problematic when running at high speeds like this.

Because of all the hassles of low-level optimisation required for high-speed sampling, you might be better off handing this task off to people who live and breathe it. e.g. [`pylsl`](https://github.com/chkothe/pylsl) provides a Python interface to the [Lab Streaming Layer](https://github.com/sccn/labstreaminglayer) (LSL), which (I think) is designed for just that sort of thing.

Also, even if you are sampling from the data at 500 Hz, you can't usefully update the plot at 500 Hz, but just at the refresh rate of your monitor (typically 60 Hz). i.e. At 500 Hz you could be collecting approximately 8 samples within each 16.666 ms screen refresh cycle. There is no point in passing each of those samples along to the graph individually, as they won't get shown on screen until the next 16.666 ms period has elapsed. So pass them in clumps, at 60 Hz (or less).

Comment: I understand the gist of what you're saying but unfortunately, I didn't understand how I would pylsl in my application. I couldn't find any help as to how I could send samples of data via an Arduino and lsl. All the examples I find give examples where they transmit random data from other full-fledged computers. Could you please help me with how I would transmit data from an Arduino using lsl?